# Can I have a primary key without clustered index ? Also can I have multivalued clustered index?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, clustered-index

Folks, I would like to understand the answer for the following questions:

1. Can I have a primary key without clustered index ? ( I am aware that when we create primary key constraint on a column, it by default creates a clustered index. So in that case, how should I deactivate clustered index ?)
2. Can I have a clustered index with multiple columns together ? (Like in non-clustered where I can join different columns for a single non-clustered index).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(This answer is for SQL Server 2005+ only. I know nothing about MySQL.)

---

> Can I have a primary key without clustered index?

Yes. As you mentioned, a primary key constraint is backed by a clustered index by default. You can tell SQL Server to back the constraint with a nonclustered index by declaring the constraint as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_MyTable
        PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED(Col1);
```

---

> Can I have a clustered index with multiple columns together ? (Like in non-clustered where I can join different columns for a single non-clustered index).

Yes, you can define an index with more than one column in the index key. It's really no different than a nonclustered index.

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_MyTable_Clus
    ON MyTable(Col1, Col2, Col3);
```

---

References: [`ALTER TABLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx), [`CREATE INDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx)

Comment: that perfectly answered my questions the way I could chew/digest. Thank you so much :) :) Cheers

Answer (score 2):

`MySQL` and `SQL-SERVER` are different RDBMS.  They have different capabilities and different syntax.

When using InnoDB, `MySQL` always makes the PK the clustered index.

`SQL-SERVER`, however, will let you create a PK without the `CLUSTERED` keyword, and let you use it within another index instead.

In both cases, PrimaryKeys and Indexes (clustered or not) can cover multiple fields.

Comment: Also, InnoDB always has a clustered index even if you don't have a primary key.

Comment: @Dems: Hi Dems, thank you for the answer. Apologize, I duno what is InnoDB, I am being newbie and sorry for silly questions. And, how do I create a PK without Clluetersted index ? I mean if I just create a table with syntax and mentioning primary key and or using the GUI tool for creating table wherein I just tick the column I need as primary key. I am really new :( Hope you understand what exactly I am behind :( I need to know the concrete way of achieving it.

Comment: The statement `SQL-SERVER ... will let you create a PK without the CLUSTERED keyword, and let you use it within another index instead.` is incorrect -- omitting the `CLUSTERED` keyword will still create a clustered index by default. You have to use the `NONCLUSTERED` keyword.