# MySQL ( InnoDB): Guid as Primary Key for a Distributed Database

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

I come from the MSSQL world and have no expert knowledge in MySQL.

Having a GUID as primary key in these two different RDBMs systems is possible. In MSSQL i better do some things in order to not run into a performance nightmare as the row count increases (many million rows).

I create the primary key as a non clustered index to prevent that the database pages change if i insert a new row. If i don't do that the system would insert the row between some existing rows and in order to do that the hard drive needs to find the right position of the page on the disc. I create a second column of a numeric type and this time as a clustered index. This guarantees that new rows will get appended on insert.

#### Question

But how i do this in MySQL? If my [information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864754/can-i-have-a-primary-key-without-clustered-index-also-can-i-have-multivalued-c) is right, i cannot force mysql to a non clustered primary key. Is this necessary or does MySQL stores the data in a manner that will not result in a performance disaster later?

#### Update: But why?

The reason i want to do this is because i want to be able to realize a distributed database.

Comment: How can you have PK as non clustered index? What is clustered index then?

Comment: Getting into the data pages is deeper than I usually go, but I can tell you using GUIDs as PK in a MySQL database is usually a bad idea when performance is of importance; it has no native support (unless something was added in more recent versions?), so you end up really just having special strings as PK.

Comment: @Andrey, being clustered doesn't mean it needs to be primary, it doesn't even have to be unique. You can have a clustered index say on lastName and a nonclustered index (be it integer, GUID, ...) as the primary key.

Comment: in your table you can have an auto-incremental int column as primary which will act as clustered indexing. for GUID you can have a varchar(36) and upon insert trigger assign a GUID. that would act as non clustered index

Comment: @Andrey the clustered index is a second column just for that.

Comment: @CetinBasoz but why? PK never changes, while lastName can change.

Comment: i updated my answer. I want to be able to have a distributed database.

Comment: Why? LastName was just a sample and why is another matter. I can choose to have an auto incrementing number as my clustered index while having a GUID as a PK. That is a perfectly valid approach. If say, you are working with disconnected data, that would prevent PK "fix ups".

Comment: Right, and thats the question. MySQL PKs are always clustered. Is that a problem?

Comment: also if you are clustering or using db farms, its worth setting the auto-incrementing value in a specific zik-zak order in the config file just to reduce master slave insert issues..  @dknaack

Comment: I am not answering in the context of MySQL No idea how and can MySQL handle it. It would be odd if it can't have nonclustered PK.

Comment: Right, but it looks like that this is the case with MySQL / InnoDB

Comment: Then, as a workaround, let it use an autoinc value as PK but behind the scenes use your indexed GUID value as your "tracker" value? That depends on your scenario. If you need to do offline manipulation then might be a valid choice.In MSSQL you simply add "NonClustered" to do that.

Comment: @krishKM can you post a sample or a link?

Comment: @CetinBasoz I still don't get why not to have GUID PK that is clustered index. That is what I did and it worked well.

Comment: @Andrey, because a GUID value would cause the data pages to be relocated and thus in an insert heavy database it would perform miserably.

Comment: @Ulueerdo,
It is not me asking why GUID is not a good choice for a clustered index but Andrey.

Comment: @CetinBasoz could you explain or maybe you have a link how GUIDs affect data pages relocation? I had no idea about it and I would like to learn more.

Comment: @Andrey, here is a link:
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190457.aspx
The index should be the same in MySQL. If it is, and if you think GUID values are not sequential values, then that would mean a new row using GUID as PK and clustered would cause rows on a page to be reloated.

Comment: I found imho a really good solution. Check out my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a Sequential GUIDs as described on

[CodeProject: GUIDs as fast primary keys under multiple databases](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/388157/GUIDs-as-fast-primary-keys-under-multiple-database).

Great performance!