# Appending primary key index to mysql (Using Mysql workbench) causing "GENERATED ALWAYS AS" error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have an existing MySQL database table running on AWS, and that I'm connected through using MySQL Workbench.

I just tried to append an auto-generated primary key to the table using the GUI, and the script that gets generated is the following:

```
ALTER TABLE `participantData`.`resources` 
ADD COLUMN `id` INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS () FIRST,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC);
```

However, upon execution, I get the following error:

```
Executing:
ALTER TABLE `participantData`.`resources` 
ADD COLUMN `id` INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS () FIRST,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC);

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GENERATED ALWAYS AS () FIRST,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQU' at line 2
```

I'm not the most eloquent with MySQL, so I'm relying entirely on the GUI for this. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking what is the current primary key, and dropping that first?

(Sorry this is posted as an answer and not a comment, I do not have enough reputation yet)

Comment: There is no primary key with the current table.

Comment: But there is a primary index.. maybe you have to explicitly define that your primary key uses a non-clustered index? See http://stackoverflow.com/q/11864754/6834603